# Counting different strings in multiple files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to count a list of smileys in a list of files (.txt) in my path /test/.

Here is my approach to count a smiley in all files.

```
    def count_string_occurrence():
        import os
        total = 0
        x = 0
        for file in os.listdir("C:/users/M/Desktop/test"):
                if file.endswith(".txt"):
                    string = ":)" #define search term
                    f=open(file,encoding="utf8")
                    contents = f.read()
                    f.close()
                    x=contents.count(string) 
                    total +=int(x) #calculate occurance of smiley in all files
        print("Number of " + string + " in all files equals " + str(total))

    count_string_occurrence()
```

How can I now loop different smileys and print the result for each smiley seperately? Since I already loop through different files it gets complicated.

Comment: What do you mean by "loop different smileys?" You want to count smileys like `:D`, `;)`, `:)`, etc?

Comment: I mean I want the script to count the numbers of around 20 smileys and output "Number of X in all files equals ___________" (X=a smiley) for each one. The smileys include :), :-), :] and some more variations of positive and negative smileys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your question: you can keep a dictionary with the count of each string and return that. But if you keep your current structure, it's not going to be nice to keep track of it.

Which leads to my suggestions:

- You're keeping the whole file in memory for no apparent reason, you can go through it line by line and check the strings in the current line.
- You're also reading the same files multiple times, while you could read them only once and check if the strings are there.
- You're checking the extension of the file, which sounds like a job for `glob`.
- You can use a `defaultdict` so you don't need to care if the count was initially `0` or not.

Modified code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import glob

SMILIES = [':)', ':P', '=]']

def count_in_files(string_list):
    results = defaultdict(int)
    for file_name in glob.iglob('*.txt'):
        print(file_name)
        with open(file_name) as input_file:
            for line in input_file:
                for s in string_list:
                    if s in line:
                        results[s] += 1
    return results

print(count_in_files(SMILIES))
```

- Lastly, with this approach, if you're using Python >= 3.5, you can change the `glob` call to `for file_name in glob.iglob('**/*.txt', recursive=True)` so it will search recursively, in case you need it.

This will print something like:

`defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {':P': 2, ':)': 1, '=]': 1})`

Comment: Thanks, this approach worked! :-) And it is indeed a lot faster than the old one.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your search string a function parameter and then call your function multiple times with different search terms.

```
def count_string_occurrence(string):
    import os
    total = 0
    x = 0
    for file in os.listdir("C:/users/M/Desktop/test"):
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            f=open(file,encoding="utf8")
            contents = f.read()
            f.close()
            x=contents.count(string)
            total +=int(x) #calculate occurance of smiley in all files
    return total

smilies = [':)', ':P', '=]']
for s in smilies =
    total = count_string_occurrence(s)
    print("Number of {} in all files equals {}".format( s, total ))
```

A different approach would be to pass a list of smilies to your function and then do the iteration inside the `if` block. Maybe store the result in a dict in the form `{ ':)': 5, ':P': 4, ... }`